# How to deal with data inconsistencies for a categorical variable?

Tags: r, data-preprocessing

I have a categorical column with 2 similar data entries: "Mobile Phone" & "Phone" but recorded as 2 different entries. How do I change one of the entries without affecting the other entries (in R)?
For example, I would want to change all "Phone" entries into "Mobile Phone".

Below are my codes that I tried but it somehow it changed my other categorical values to a NA:

```
dataset2$PreferredLoginDevice <- factor(dataset2$PreferredLoginDevice,
                      levels = 'Phone',
                      labels = 'Mobile Phone')
```

[Summary statistics of my categorical column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxe25.png)

Comment: You appear to have defined a factor with only one valid level.  I suspect that's why the other entries have become `NA`s.

Comment: @Limey hey thanks a lot. I managed to resolve my problem